# will it be easy to go from directx 9 to directx 11

Tags: directx-11, directx-9

I am using an old machine with windows xp on it, and xp supports only DirectX9, and i want to learn directx 11 and use it, so my question is : is it okey to begin learning directX 9 then go to 11 after getting my new machine with windows 8 ?
What are the major differences between Directx 9 and 11 ?
PS: my goal is to create a 3D Game.

Comment: While some of the concepts are similar, there's a decade or more of difference between the experience of using Direct3D 9 with the legacy DirectX SDK on Windows XP vs. Direct3D 11 on Windows 8.x. In any case, the basics of porting is covered on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166881.aspx) and [Migrating to Direct3D 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476190.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between D3D 9 and 10/11 is that the fixed pipeline no longer exists, so when working with 9 I recommend avoiding the fixed pipeline and writing your own shaders for everything.  I would also consider avoiding the effects framework as this has moved out of the main libraries in 10/11 (although it is still available).

Another difference is in how D3D handles its device contexts.  A lot of the functions have been moved from the Device to the Context class, this is done to allow better multithreading support with deferred contexts.  This shouldn't affect you too much though, it will just require a bit of refactoring when you upgrade.

If you plan to make your game with legacy support for xp/dx9 then beginning the project using 9 might not be a bad idea anyway, good luck!